# How can I re-create this Javascript array structure in Go?

Tags: javascript, go

I have this Javascript array, how can I recreate it in Go? I'm completely lost on how to create so many nested slices or arrays.

```
var jsArray = [
    [
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
    ],
    [
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        []
    ]
];
```

JSON output:

```
[[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your example may be over-simplified, as it's not clear what the purpose of this data structure is (it doesn't contain any "real" data). If you just want anything that resembles this pattern, there might be a lot of options.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that the values that you will store in your current JS array will look like this

```js
var jsArray = [
    [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6],
        [7, 8],
        [9, 10]
    ],
    [
        [11, 12],
        [13, 14],
        [15, 16],
        [17, 18],
        [19, 20]
    ]
];
```

The same values can be stored in the Golang slices like this

```golang
goSlice := [][][]int{
    {
        []int{1, 2},
        []int{3, 4},
        []int{5, 6},
        []int{7, 8},
        []int{9, 10},
    },
    {
        []int{11, 12},
        []int{13, 14},
        []int{15, 16},
        []int{17, 18},
        []int{19, 20},
    },
}
```

The output for the above slice looks like this

> [[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8] [9 10]] [[11 12] [13 14] [15 16] [17 18] [19
> 20]]]

which is identical to the `jsArray` structure.

Instead of slices if you want to use array than you can use the define it like this

```golang
goArray := [2][5][2]int{
    {
        [2]int{1, 2},
        [2]int{3, 4},
        [2]int{5, 6},
        [2]int{7, 8},
        [2]int{9, 10},
    },
    {
        [2]int{11, 12},
        [2]int{13, 14},
        [2]int{15, 16},
        [2]int{17, 18},
        [2]int{19, 20},
    },
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: In the nested slice/array literal, you can omit the repeated `[]int`s or `[2]int`s to make it a bit more tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func main() {
    var jsArray [2][5][0]int
    fmt.Println(jsArray)
}
```

You can create your nested slice and describe the length of each slice it contains going from the outside in.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/go/go_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm